# Capturar valor de un TextBox y comprobar que sea igual a otro valor en C#

Tags: c#

Me gustaría que cuando el usuario ponga exactamente algo en un *TextBox*, como por ejemplo `1234`, que se pueda abrir luego otra ventana, pero sólo si pone eso en concreto.

Entonces, ¿Cómo puedo comprobar que lo ingresado por el usuario sea `1234`?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para capturar los datos ingresados por el usuario en el cuadro de texto (TextBox) existen, principalmente, 4 eventos. 3 de los cuatro ocurren cuando el usuario está presionando las teclas para ingresar información al TextBox, estos son: `KeyDown`, `KeyPress` y `KeyUp`. El cuarto evento ocurre cuando la propiedad `Text` del TextBox cambia, es decir, cuando el usuario termina de ingresar la información en el TextBox y éste pierde el foco.

> Si haces uso de los eventos `KeyDown`, `KeyPress` y `KeyUp` para verificar la entrada del usuario, debes tener en cuenta que estos eventos se producen en un orden, que es el siguiente:
>
> 1. KeyDown
> 2. KeyPress
> 3. KeyUp

Y al implementarlos en tu código, estarían construidos así:

### KeyDown

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(textBox1.Text.Equals("1234"))
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("debo lanzar la segunda ventana"); 
    } 
}
```

### KeyPress

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(textBox1.Text.Equals("1234"))
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("debo lanzar la segunda ventana"); 
    } 
}
```

### KeyUp

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(textBox1.Text.Equals("1234"))
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("debo lanzar la segunda ventana"); 
    } 
}
```

Si quieres verificar los escrito por el usuario en el TextBox, el código del la función lanza el evento sería la siguiente:

### TextChanged

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(textBox1.Text.Equals("1234"))
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("debo lanzar la segunda ventana"); 
    } 
}
```

Recuerda que para que se ejecuten estas funciones debes relacionar a la función con el evento del TextBox. Ahora sólo depende en qué momento o en qué frecuencia necesitas validar la entrada del usuario.

> Un evento, según esta [página](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/awbftdfh(VS.80).aspx)  del sitio de la MSDN de Microsoft es:
>
> Los eventos proporcionan un medio de que una clase u objeto informe a otras clases u objetos cuando sucede algo relevante. La clase que envía (o produce) el evento recibe el nombre de editor y las clases que reciben (o controlan) el evento se denominan suscriptores.

Más contenido en el sitio de MSDN de Microsoft:

> En estas páginas encontrarás más información de los eventos [TextBox.KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx), [TextBox.KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx), [TextBox.KeyUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) y [TextBox.TextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Debes añadir el Evento KeyPress a tu  TextBox para validar cada vez que se presione una tecla :

```
 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
 { 
    //validamos el texto que tiene el textBox
    if(textBox1.text.equals("1234"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("debo lanzar la segunda ventana");
    } 
 }
```

Espero te sirva 
Saludos.

Comment: Hola, es que la verdad apenas estoy aprendiendo a manejar interfaz y c#, me podrías decir que es un evento, porfa?  porque cuando pongo para programar el textbox me aparece es esto:                                          private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)              {         }

Comment: estas utilizando visual Studio ?

Comment: Sí, estoy utilizando visual Studio

Comment: En el Editor visual , debes seleccionar el control al cual le deseas añadir un evento , luego en la ventana de property debes buscar el simbolo de un rayo, ahora estaras viendo todos los eventos disponibles solo debes hacer doble click y el editor añadira el codigo correspondiente , Saludos

Comment: ahh listo ya entendí eso, ahora podrías mirar porfa las nuevas imágenes que puse? Lo que hago es lo sgte, creo una variable validar qu si entra en el if (si ponen la contraseña 1234) se convierta en 1, y cuando de clic en el botón si validar =1, entonces que me aparezca otra ventana. pero no me quiere dar.      Mil gracias por tu ayuda!